# Django: Unresolved reference 'project_name' warning

Tags: python, django, pycharm, user-permissions

I'm using [django-role-permissions](https://django-role-permissions.readthedocs.io) module to support roles in django. I followed the instrunctions from [here](https://django-role-permissions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html).

I added `roles.py` in `project_mytif` folder.  `roles.py` is the same folder as `settings.py` and in `settings.py` I added `ROLEPERMISSIONS_MODULE = 'project_mytif.roles'`.

The `roles.py` has the code below:

```
from rolepermissions.roles import AbstractUserRole

class Doctor(AbstractUserRole):
    available_permissions = {
        'create_medical_record': True,
    }

class Nurse(AbstractUserRole):
    available_permissions = {
        'edit_patient_file': True,
    }
```

In my app folder I created the `permissions.py` file and I'm trying to import using:

```
from project_mytif.roles import Doctor, Nurse
```

but I get a message: `Unresolved reference 'project_mytif'`.

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Alasdair `roles.py` is the same folder as `settings.py` and in `settings.py` I added `ROLEPERMISSIONS_MODULE = 'project_mytif.roles'`.

Comment: Are you actually getting an error when you run your code, or is this just a warning from PyCharm?

Comment: @Alasdair Just a warning from Pycharm.

Comment: It looks like a PyCharm configuration issue, not a problem with any of the code you have shown.